# how to select the second element with the same name & xpath?

Tags: python, selenium

In the web Application i have selected an element using name or xpath & send keys to it is working fine, in the same application i have to send keys to another element which has same xpath & name but it is selecting the first element. how to resolve this ambiguity & select the elements separately

Answer (score 2):

driver.find_elements_by_tag_name("img")[1]

same with xpath